# How to use customer filter in html? django (for loop with number)

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop

It's the first time I use the custom filters. Sorry if it seems too newbie..

So I am using this filter: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/
to iterate through a number in html.

--project
  --my app
     --templatetags
       --otherfilter.py
       --helper.py

in helper.py I have exactly the same code as in the link.
In html I have:

```
                        <div class="es-carousel">
                            <ul>
                                {% load helper %}
                                {% measurement.set.total | num_rangenum_range  %}

                                <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/thumbs/{{counter}}.jpg" data-large="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/2.jpg" alt="image02" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/thumbs/{{counter}}.jpg" data-large="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/3.jpg" alt="image03" data-description="A plaintful story from a sistering vale" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/thumbs/4.jpg" data-large="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/4.jpg" alt="image04" data-description="My spirits to attend this double voice accorded" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/thumbs/5.jpg" data-large="images/5.jpg" alt="image05" data-description="And down I laid to list the sad-tuned tale" /></a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images-gallery/thumbs/6.jpg" data-large="images/6.jpg" alt="image06" data-description="Ere long espied a fickle maid full pale" /></a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

measurement.set.total is a number I get from my models.
and also please help with the counters that I want to access in my file directory.

Comment: If you have the same code you should use it in the same way as in the link you provided

Comment: thanks! It was actually a typo that causing problem...@Gocht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is provided in the web page. It used to not work because my silly typo in the templatetags.

```
{% load helper %}
{% num_range 5 as some_range %}

{% for i in some_range %}
  {{ i }}: Something I want to repeat\n
{% endfor %}
```